# Selenium Firefox in headless running from a Celery task - Webdriver unexpectedly closes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, celery

Running Selenium from a Flask app / with Celery task in headless mode. I get the error message: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127` Here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import sys, os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from check_email import EmailedReferrals, Referrals
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Date, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime
from check_email import EmailedReferrals, Referrals
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('celery')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


load_dotenv()

env_conf = os.getenv("CONFIG")
Base = declarative_base()

if env_conf == "dev":    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DEV_DATABASE_URL')    
else: 
    # Set up Firefox options
    options = Options()
    # Set window size
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("-headless")
    # Include the path to the Firefox binary
    firefox_binary_path = '/usr/bin/firefox'
    geckodriver_path = '/home/fusion/bin/geckodriver'
    options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
    service = Service(executable_path=geckodriver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
    DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('PROD_DATABASE_URL')
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

def get_row_xpath(row, cell): #pulls xpath of rows and cells from Incoming Referrals View
    ctl = str(row).zfill(2)
    action = row - 3
    id_cell = f"""/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody\
        /tr/td[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[{row}]/td[{cell}]"""
    select_element = f"""//*[@id="ucViewGrid_dgView_ctl{ctl}_Actions_{action}_0_0_ActionItems"]"""
    go_button = f"""#ucViewGrid_dgView_ctl{ctl}_Actions_{action}_0_0_ActionButton > input:nth-child(1)"""
    return id_cell, select_element, go_button


def main(referral_id_from_flask, comment):
    print('hello from main')
    logger.info("hello from main")
    driver.get("https://www.example.com")
    #Click Account and sign in
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="UserNameTextBox"]').send_keys(os.getenv('USERNAME'))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="PasswordTextBox"]').send_keys(os.getenv('PASSWORD'))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnLoginHack"]').click()
    sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl13"]').click()
    #loop through table
    cell = 3
    for row in range(3, 52):
        logger.info(f"Looping: {row}")
        print(f"Loop #: {row}")
        id_cell = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, get_row_xpath(row, cell)[0]).text
        referral_id = id_cell.split('\n')[0].strip()
        #find row with the correct
        if referral_id == referral_id_from_flask:
            #Select View Online Referral
            select_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, get_row_xpath(row, cell)[1])
            select = Select(select_element)
            select.select_by_visible_text("View")
            #click go
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, get_row_xpath(row, cell)[2]).click()
            #we are in View Online Referral of the patient
            #Find select box
            #select value 0  which is accept patient
            select_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@id="dgProviders_ctl02_ddResponse"]""" )
            select = Select(select_element)
            select.select_by_value("1")
            sleep(0.5)
            #comment box
            # wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be present and clickable
            comment_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dgProviders_ctl02_txtProviderComments"]'))
            )
            comment_box.clear()
            sleep(0.5) # Add a small delay here
            comment_box.send_keys(comment)
            sleep(0.5) # Add a small delay here
            #click send response
            #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@id="ButtonBarSendResponse"]""").click()
            #add to query
            r = session.query(Referrals).filter(Referrals.referral_id == int(referral_id)).first()
            r.referral_acceptence_status = "accepted"
            session.commit()
            session.close()
            print('done')
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    referral_id_from_flask = sys.argv[1]
    comment = sys.argv[2]
    main(referral_id_from_flask, comment)
```

And the complete stack trace:

```
[2023-04-17 09:35:13,375: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fusion/scrapers/care_portal/accept.py", line 43, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
  File "/home/fusion/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 199, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options, keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/fusion/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/fusion/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/fusion/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/fusion/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed several SO posts from you about this topic. I found them because I've been pounding my head against the same set of errors for the past 2.5 days. I finally figured it out last night and I think my solution may help you.

My use case is a Flask training application using RQ and Redis to execute asynchronous tasks that use Selenium to behave as a bot-user of the same application. Various user behaviors trigger the bot to do various things. For example, if someone sends an internal message to the administrator, then it will trigger the bot to log in as the administrator, read the message, and respond to it. I chose Selenium and not inline code because I want the server to log the traffic as if the actions were being taken by a real user.

Each of these errors (the various ones you encountered) are related to a different system configuration/permission. The 127 error has to do with a command not being found, and the 1 error has to do with an issue or problem causing the program to exit. These are the toughest to solve because various things could cause these conditions and exception messaging is extremely vague. The remaining errors are pretty straightforward. Unfortunately, I don't have solutions mapped directly to errors, but the following configurations solved them all.

1. Install and configure the Selenium driver (Firefox, Chrome, etc.). I put it in `/usr/bin`. The specific location isn't as important as how everything else is set up. Make sure the driver is owned by `root` (`sudo chown root:root <driver_file>`) and executable. I used 755 file permissions (`sudo chmod 755 <driver_file>`).
2. Make sure the worker service is running as a user with a writeable home directory. I am using `root`, which I don't recommend for security reasons, but there's no risk in my use case. I typically run all of my web services and apps using a restricted user account such as `www-data`. While this is a good thing and works really well in most cases, Selenium behaves like an interactive user and needs a home folder to work with. The `www-data` user does not have write access to its own home folder at `/var/www`, which is owned by `root`. This will not play well with Selenium. If you want to run the worker service with an account like `www-data`, then it needs to own, or at least have write permissions, to its home directory (`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`). This was a doozy of a problem to figure out. Configuring Selenium to use a custom profile path that was writeable for `www-data` did not work for me.
3. Make sure the worker's environment has the location of the driver in the path. In my case, `/usr/bin`. I was hung up on this one for a while because I set the path for the app and not the worker. Configuring Selenium to use a custom driver path through it's various code-level configurations instead of adding to the worker's path did not work for me.
4. Configure your driver like this in the code. This example uses Firefox, so there may be slight differences for Chrome. Note that the custom `log_path` needs to be writeable if you are using a user with restricted permissions, and make sure that the log file doesn't already exist at that path. Not doing this could result in various issues related to permissions.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService

   # setup Firefox webdriver options
   options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
   options.add_argument('--headless')
   # inizialize Firefox webdriver
   service = FirefoxService(log_path='/tmp/geckodriver.log')
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up running Celery from inside of a Screen instead of as a service. I can't explain why it worked, but it did. I simply run a cron job to restart the screen at reboot and it works like a charm.